# Linux MinGW: on compiling he output list of 8 "nultiple definitions"

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, mingw, mingw-w64

Неllо еvеrybоdу!

I try to compile program with MinGW on Linux:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -static -mwindows ./obj/CFLF.o ./obj/resources.o -o ./bin/CFLF.exe
```

and catch this output:

```
./mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:171: multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2-win32/../../../../i686-w64-
mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:./mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:171: first 
defined here
./obj/CFLF.o: In function `mainCRTStartup':
./mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:199: multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2-win32/../../../../i686-w64-
mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:./mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:199: first 
defined here
./obj/CFLF.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x500): multiple definition of `__gcc_register_frame'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2-win32/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:
(.text+0x0): first defined here
./obj/CFLF.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x560): multiple definition of __gcc_deregister_frame'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2-win32/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:
(.text+0x60): first defined here
./obj/CFLF.o:crtexe.c:(.CRT+0x10): multiple definition of `mingw_pcinit'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2-win32/../../../../i686-w64-
mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:./mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:118: first 
defined here
./obj/CFLF.o:crtexe.c:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__mingw_winmain_nShowCmd'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2-win32/../../../../i686-w64-
mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:./mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:118: first 
defined here
./obj/CFLF.o:crtexe.c:(.CRT+0x4): multiple definition of `mingw_pcppinit'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2-win32/../../../../i686-w64-
mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:./mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:118: first 
defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2-win32/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:
(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `_Jv_RegisterClasses'
```

Why? My code's point is WinMain, not WinMainCRTStartup or mainCRTStartup.

I write [link to code](https://github.com/mkostoevr/CHT-FR-LTS-FSH/tree/master/new/MinGW), because is so big (GitHub).

P.S.: I compile this code with MinGW on Windows and hasn't this errors.
P.P.S.: Why I not use Windows? Just for base education.

Comment: How did you create the object files?

Comment: Looks like your trying to compile a windows executable on Linux.  I don't believe that will work.

Comment: @Nathan With properly set cross-compiling options, it might work well.

Comment: _@Magomed_ Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: @NathanOliver, it not compilling, it CrossCompiling. I cross compile little programs on linux, and they are work on Windows.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, with commands "i686-w64-mingw32-g++ ./src/main.cpp ./src/downloader.cpp -o ./obj/CFLF.o -lwinhttp
" and "i686-w64-mingw32-windres ./src/resources.rc -o ./obj/resources.o". they created without errors.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I read The Tour, my question is bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't create object files, but *executable* files that you then attempt to link together.

The command

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ ./src/main.cpp ./src/downloader.cpp -o ./obj/CFLF.o -lwinhttp
```

should really be

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ ./src/main.cpp -c -o ./obj/main.o
```

That will create the *object* file `./obj/main.o` that you in a later stage use for the actual linking. The three big differences is that you don't provide multiple source files, you use the `-c` option will tells the GCC frontend program to only compile into object files, and you don't provide a library (which is only used when linking).

This needs to be done for *all* source files.

Then you can link all the object files together:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ ./obj/main.o ./obj/downloader.o ./obj/resources.o -o ./bin/CFLF.exe -lwinhttp
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you wery much!